# Visual Studio Setup not installinig Crystal Report in Unattended installation

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports-2008, ini, silent-installer

I want to deploy VS2008 in unattended mode. So I created an ini file using createunattend switch with all my features required. But I can see that after VS installation Cystal Report is not getting installed (Checked Crystal reports while creating ini file). Can anyone help how to install crystal report while installing VS2008 in un attend installation.

And I try installing Crystal Report separately (crystal report msi) but after installation when I open Crystal report project I am getting "Invalid Keycode message"

Is there any solution for any of the above issue?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution..
Installed Crystal report msi and passed a PIDKEY= as a MSI paramer that worked. I got the  when I installed Visual studio 2008 manually with crystal report and went to Help about there I can see that the key specific for Crystal Report.